# Magento 2.4, Error: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: composer

I'm trying to install extinctions to Magento 2.4 and I have the following error:

composer command: **composer require mageplaza/module-core**

```
    Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - magento/composer-root-update-plugin is locked to version 1.0.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - magento/composer-root-update-plugin 1.0.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.
  Problem 2
    - dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer is locked to version v0.5.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer v0.5.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.
  Problem 3
    - laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin 1.0.4 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.1 requires laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin ^1.0 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin[1.0.4].
    - magento/product-community-edition is locked to version 2.4.1 and an update of this package was not requested.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `"magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~1.1",` from the <project_root>/composer.json file then run

```
composer update

composer require mageplaza/module-core
```

This should solve the problem!